# Как передать данные из виджета Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def registration():
    button = tk.Button(text = "Зарегистрироваться" , command =  get_entry).place(x = 400 , y = 340)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Придумайте свой ник" ,   font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 400 , y = 100)
    entry = tk.Entry().place(x = 400, y = 120)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Адрес электронной почты" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 400 , y = 160)
    entry3 = tk.Entry().place(x = 400, y = 300)
def get_entry():
    s = entry.get()
    print(s)
```

Как получить  из виджета entry значение которого ввел пользователь, при нажатии на кнопку? Возникает ошибка NameError.

Comment: `place(x = 400 , y = ` - а тут где конец?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry` - локальная переменная функции `registration`, она видна только в этой функции. Есть несколько способов решения вашей проблемы:

1. создавать виджеты вне функций, так что `entry` станет глобальной переменной, доступной для всех функций
2. объявить переменную `entry` глобальной в функции `registration`:

   ```
   def registration():
       global entry
       # Дальше остальной код функции
   ```
3. переместить функцию `get_entry` внутрь `registration`, так что `get_entry` будет видеть все переменные внешней функции:

   ```
   def registration():
       def get_entry():
           s = entry.get()
           print(s)

       button = tk.Button(text = "Зарегистрироваться" , command =  get_entry).place(x = 400 , y = 340)
       # Дальше остальной код
   ```
4. передавать entry внутрь обработчика нажатия как параметр через лямбду: `command=lambda: get_entry(entry)` + добавить параметр `entry` в `get_entry`:

   ```
   def get_entry(entry):
       s = entry.get()
       print(s)
   ```
5. обернуть все в класс, сделать `entry` полем объекта, а функции `registration` и `get_entry` - методами, доступ к полям объекта будет через `self` (`self.entry`, например).

Comment: Спасибо большое!